# MySQL Database JOIN tables and Search WHERE <multiple-columns>

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 tables **tweet**, **room**, **room_tweet**:

```
       tweet                    room                          room_tweet
+----+------+-----+     +----+------+-----+     +----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | text | ... |     | id | name | ... |     | id | room_id | tweet_id | disabled |
+----+------+-----+     +----+------+-----+     +----+---------+----------+----------+
| 10 | a... | ... |     | 20 | a... | ... |     | 80 |   20    |    10    |     1    |
| 11 | b... | ... |     | 21 | b... | ... |     | 81 |   20    |    11    |     0    |
| 12 | c... | ... |     | 22 | c... | ... |     | 82 |   21    |    10    |     1    |
| 13 | d... | ... |     +----+------+-----+     | 83 |   20    |    12    |     1    |
+----+------+-----+                             | 84 |   22    |    10    |     0    |
                                                | 85 |   21    |    11    |     1    |
                                                +----+---------+----------+----------+
```

I need a query that gets all **tweets** and show the **disabled** state in a specific **room**.

All **tweets** are displayed in all **rooms**, each **tweet** has a **disabled** state and is different on each **room** (same **tweet** has a different **disabled** state in each **room**) this is achieved with the **room_tweet** table.

This is the query I've written so far:

```
SELECT t.id AS tweet_id, t.text AS tweet, rt.disabled, r.id AS room_id, r.name AS room  
FROM tweet as t 
LEFT JOIN room_tweet as rt ON t.id = rt.tweet_id 
LEFT JOIN room as r ON rt.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = 21 OR r.id IS NULL
```

Not all **tweets** are in the **room_tweet** table to associate them to a **room**. Therefore many **tweets** will have a **NULL** reference to a **room** in the **result set**, and the same goes for the **room**, some **rooms** will have no **tweets** associated to them. [This does not mean that the **tweet** should not appear on the **result set**.]

All **tweets** should appear in the **result set** once (ONLY ONE TIME) with a **disabled** state of [1, 0 or NULL].

It would be a simple query if all **tweets** happened to have an association on the **room_tweet** table, but this is not the case. Since **tweets** are created throughout the day and **rooms** are created randomly the **room_tweet** table will not, and should not have all associations.

```
Result without WHERE:
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+
| tweet_id | tweet | disabled | room_id | room |
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+
|    10    | a...  |    1     |    20   | a... |
|    10    | a...  |    1     |    21   | b... |
|    10    | a...  |    0     |    22   | c... |
|    11    | b...  |    0     |    20   | a... |
|    11    | b...  |    1     |    21   | b... |
|    12    | c...  |    1     |    20   | a... |
|    13    | d...  |   NULL   |   NULL  | NULL |
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+
Tweets are duplicated multiple times ex: tweet 10 shows 3 times.

Result with (WHERE r.id = 21 OR r.id IS NULL)
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+
| tweet_id | tweet | disabled | room_id | room |
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+
|    10    | a...  |    1     |    21   | b... |
|    11    | b...  |    1     |    21   | b... |
|    13    | d...  |   NULL   |   NULL  | NULL |
+----------+-------+----------+---------+------+    
Tweets are missing!, only tweet with id 10, 11 and 13 show up. This is because 
the other tweets have been associated with other rooms and therefore are not 
**NULL** anymore. (All tweets should appear once).
```

As you can see on the **result set**, not all **tweets** are being displayed (when **WHERE** is being used) and the other problem is that **tweets** that have been associated with multiple **rooms** on the **room_tweet** table, therefore they are being duplicated on the **result set**. (I only want to see each **tweet** once!)

So the question is: What am I missing on the **query** and is it even possible to get the **result** that I'm expecting?

Is it possible to fix this behavior? if so, is my query the problem or are the tables wrong?

If you want to test the queries here is the SQL to create all tables and data in phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE `room` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `...` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '...', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;
CREATE TABLE `tweet` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `text` varchar(140) NOT NULL, `...` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '...', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
CREATE TABLE `room_tweet` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `tweet_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `fk_room_tweet_1` (`room_id`), KEY `fk_room_tweet_2` (`tweet_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=86 ;
ALTER TABLE `room_tweet` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_room_tweet_1` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `room` (`id`), ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_room_tweet_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tweet_id`) REFERENCES `tweet` (`id`);    
INSERT INTO `room` (`id`, `name`, `...`) VALUES (20, 'a...', '...'), (21, 'b...', '...'), (22, 'c...', '...');    
INSERT INTO `tweet` (`id`, `text`, `...`) VALUES (10, 'a...', '...'), (11, 'b...', '...'), (12, 'c...', '...'), (13, 'd...', '...');
INSERT INTO `room_tweet` (`id`, `room_id`, `tweet_id`, `disabled`) VALUES (80, 20, 10, 1), (81, 20, 11, 0), (82, 21, 10, 1), (83, 20, 12, 1), (84, 22, 10, 0), (85, 21, 11, 1);
```

I've tried JOIN, INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, and noon seem to fix my problem.

Thanks for your time, and once again, the only thing I need is a **result set** that gets all **tweets** that show the **disabled** state on that specific **room**. If it doesn't have a **disabled** state **NULL** should appear.

So far the best Result has been this:

```
SELECT t.id AS tweet_id, t.text AS tweet, rt.disabled, r.id AS room_id, r.name AS room  
FROM tweet as t 
LEFT JOIN room_tweet as rt ON t.id = rt.tweet_id 
LEFT JOIN room as r ON rt.room_id = r.id
```

Once again thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `r.id` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT t.id AS tweet_id, t.text AS tweet, rt.disabled, r.id AS room_id, r.name AS room  
FROM tweet as t 
LEFT JOIN room_tweet as rt ON t.id = rt.tweet_id 
LEFT JOIN room as r ON rt.room_id = r.id and r.id = 21;
```

With this query, things will only match when they are in room 21.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have solved my problem.
The only thing I had to change (to prevent tweet duplication) was move the delimiter to the first LEFT JOIN ----->
LEFT JOIN room_tweet as rt ON t.id = rt.tweet_id AND rt.room_id = 21